# iTunesConnect sign in trouble

Tags: app-store-connect

I have trouble with *iTunesConnect*.

Since yesterday my **Apple developer account is activated**. 
When I sign in the **Dev Centers it's working fine**. 
**But** on *iTunesConnect*, when I try to sign in, I'm connecting to **an account where I'm admin AND NOT legal** (*it's the same apple id*, I'm connecting to an account **where i'm just a user not the owner**).

How to sign in **my own dev account** ?

Answer (score 1):

If your Apple ID works to log you into iTunes Connect and you lack some authorities on your primary Apple ID - here are the things I would do in order:

1. Log out and then open a private browsing / incognito window and then log back in without any pesky cookies or other history.
2. Go to **Agreements, Tax, and Banking** and verify that you have two valid Master Agreements that are both effective and not expired and then click done.
3. Go to **Users and Roles** and click on the AppleID you are using.
4. Go to **Roles** and verify that the Legal and Admin check boxes are grey and selected. [image: iTunes Connect - Users and Roles]
5. Repeat the above step for any additional AppleID that are associated with your account to verify the proper roles for each (if you have secondary accounts).
6. If all else fails, go to **Resources and Help** and click the **Contact Us** to request one-on-one help with your specific account since you will be unlikely to fix whatever is wrong at that point yourself on iTunes Connect since it would be a server side data issue and/or that you haven't accepted the required legal agreements during the sign up and activation process.

Comment: This not the problem. I use the same Apple ID for Role as Admin on a friend's dev account and on my own dev account.
And I cannot sign in my personnal dev account. I'm always as admin on the account of my friend